# Error when I tried to add dependency to build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I didn't find answer for me. This is my problem:

I want to use `Google Sign-In` in my app. When I started to add google library I got this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processBetaGoogleServices'.
```

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

This is my `gradle` files:

**Top** level:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App** level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }    
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How to fix my error?

Comment: remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` from top .You can use `10.0.0` version

Comment: Then `clean-rebuild` and run .Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
```

change the **play-services-auth dependency** as above code snippet,and remove the plugin at the top i.e.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: and for butterknife,use  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'